# pddl precondtion not working correctly in the plan

Tags: artificial-intelligence, fault, preconditions, planning, pddl

I am working on a project in pddl. The idea is to pick four balls and transfer them to the conveyer. (defined in the goal) The simple pickup, move and drop actions work fine but when I try to make it more complicated for eg. by adding different poses for the robot,detecting the item before picking, the plan does not follow the pre-condition. For e.g. focus on the pick action, The correct pose is not followed. Any ideas regarding the mistake in the code? The final plan should to have correct pose for the each action and detect the item one by one and not all at once

link below:
http://editor.planning.domains/#read_session=BzTaNrk4dQ

faulty output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubWS8.png

Comment: No faulty output plan appears. If you would like help to diagnose, I'd suggest posting the domain / problem on http://editor.planning.domains/ and then saving a session (you can post the read-only link here for us to take a look at).

Comment: Post edited as per the recommendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks haz for going through the code.
I was able to debug it. the assignment of preconditions  was incorrect. the correct way of assigning a value to a parameter is the following:

(= ?p findshirt)

in the above line you assign findshirt type to 'p'

Answer (score 0):

Likely something missing/wrong in the precondition. You have this for the `pickup` action:

```
(exists (?f - pose ?g - gripper)
        (at-pose robotarm pregrasppose))
```

Note that you don't use the variables `?f` and `?g` at all in the fluent.